# How to provide credentials for Docker commands without first using `docker login`?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, cloud

I would like to know whether it's possible to provide credentials for the remote registry for Docker commands like `docker pull ... <image>` or `docker run ... <image>` without first using `docker login`?

The reason is that I'd like to supply the credentials (inline) like in HTTP Basic Auth, so that I don't have to  create `~/.docker/config.json`.

Experimenting with `<username>:<password>@<image>` doesn't seem to work, at least for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achived using the Docker HTTP API via `curl` or equivalent.

See the official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#operation/ImageCreate

> The Engine API is an HTTP API served by Docker Engine. It is the API
> the Docker client uses to communicate with the Engine, so everything
> the Docker client can do can be done with the API.
>
> Most of the client's commands map directly to API endpoints (e.g.
> docker ps is GET /containers/json). The notable exception is running
> containers, which consists of several API calls.

**Reverse Engineering**:

First create a Unix socket for inspecting `docker` client requests:

```
socat -v UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/fake,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Next, use the `docker` client to run `docker pull ...`:

```
docker -H unix:///tmp/fake pull db-docker-xsrt-rt.artifactory.example.net/aquasec/kube-hunter
```

HTTP traffic sent between `docker` client and `dockerd` server:

```
> 2021/04/13 12:42:21.445593  length=80 from=0 to=79
GET /_ping HTTP/1.1\r
Host: docker\r
User-Agent: Docker-Client/18.09.6 (linux)\r
\r
< 2021/04/13 12:42:21.446085  length=212 from=0 to=211
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r
Api-Version: 1.39\r
Docker-Experimental: false\r
Ostype: linux\r
Server: Docker/18.09.6 (linux)\r
Date: Tue, 13 Apr 2021 10:42:21 GMT\r
Content-Length: 2\r
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r
\r
OK> 2021/04/13 12:42:21.447291  length=401 from=80 to=480
POST /v1.39/images/create?fromImage=db-docker-xsrt-rt.artifactory.example.net%2Faquasec%2Fkube-hunter&tag=latest HTTP/1.1\r
Host: docker\r
User-Agent: Docker-Client/18.09.6 (linux)\r
Content-Length: 0\r
Content-Type: text/plain\r
X-Registry-Auth: <redacted>\r
\r
< 2021/04/13 12:42:21.546168  length=352 from=212 to=563
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r
Api-Version: 1.39\r
Content-Type: application/json\r
Docker-Experimental: false\r
Ostype: linux\r
Server: Docker/18.09.6 (linux)\r
Date: Tue, 13 Apr 2021 10:42:21 GMT\r
Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r
\r
3d\r
{"status":"Pulling from aquasec/kube-hunter","id":"latest"}\r
\r
45\r
{"status":"Already exists","progressDetail":{},"id":"801bfaa63ef2"}\r
\r
< 2021/04/13 12:42:21.552481  length=811 from=564 to=1374
...
```

The relevant part is the following, where credentials from `~/docker/config.json` are provided Base64 encoded via `X-Registry-Auth` HTTP header:

```
POST /v1.39/images/create?fromImage=db-docker-xsrt-rt.artifactory.example.net%2Faquasec%2Fkube-hunter&tag=latest HTTP/1.1\r
Host: docker\r
User-Agent: Docker-Client/18.09.6 (linux)\r
Content-Length: 0\r
Content-Type: text/plain\r
X-Registry-Auth: <redacted>\r
\r
```

Decoding the `X-Registry-Auth` value yields something like (redacted):

```
echo <redacted> | base64 -d
{"username":"<redacted","password":"<redacted>","serveraddress":"db-docker-xsrt-rt.artifactory.example.net"}
```